# Send email with attachment in Ruby

Tags: ruby, email, attachment

I need to send an email with an attachment via Ruby.

Been searching around but haven't found any simple script example to do this.

Closest I've found is ActionMailer but that seems to require a bunch of other scripts to to run. (NOTE: I am not using Ruby on Rails)

Answer (score 18):

Have you checked out [Mail](http://github.com/mikel/mail)?  That is what the new ActionMailer API in Rails 3 is built upon.

*"Mail is an internet library for Ruby that is designed to handle emails generation, parsing and sending in a simple, rubyesque manner."*

Here comes a quick example from the docs:

```
require 'mail'

@mail = Mail.new
file_data = File.read('path/to/myfile.pdf')
@mail.attachments['myfile.pdf'] = { :mime_type => 'application/x-pdf',
                                    :content => file_data }
```

**Update**: Or even more simply:

```
@mail = Mail.new
@mail.add_file("/path/to/file.jpg")
```

Comment: @sergiovilar: Mail is a pure Ruby library. It does not depend on Rails. Hence it is a valid answer (even today, 6 years after the answer was posted).

Comment: I am getting this error: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 2):

Sending Email or Email with any type of attachment has become more simple with the "mail" gem installation.

Step:1 Install "mail" gem

Step:2 In the ruby file maintain the syntax given below:

```ruby
require 'mail'
def mailsender
      Mail.defaults do
        delivery_method :smtp,{ address: "<smtp_address>",openssl_verify_mode: "none" }
      end

      Mail.deliver do
        from     'from_mail_id'
        to       'to_mail_id'
        subject  'subject_to_be_sent'
        # body     File.read('body.txt')
        body     'body.txt'
        add_file '<file_location>/Word Doc.docx'
        add_file '<file_location>/Word Doc.doc'
      end
end
```

Step:3 now Just call the method in the step definition.

Answer (score 1):

Full documentation: [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail)

```
require 'mail'

Mail.deliver do
  from      "bob@example.com"
  to        "alice@example.com"
  subject   "Email with attachment"
  body      "Hello world"
  add_file  "/path/to/file"
end
```